# plotting Jacobian elliptic function

Tags: graphing-functions

How can I plot bellow function in MATHEMATICA, MATLAB, or MAPLE?

Here $cn$ is the Jacobi elliptic function:

$$ f(x)=0.7951556995+0.0048443005cn^2(0.4831042546x,0.1118800243)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mathematica:

```
Plot[0.7951556995 + 0.0048443005 JacobiCN[0.4831042546 x,0.1118800243]^2,{x,0,5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by about 11 seconds!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm pretty sure you have a prettier version =) Please post it, we all can learn from it

Comment: Nope... basically the same...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The basic form is a little complicated. It is from cnoidal waves in plasma.

Comment: @sepideshirazi:  A request:  Ask the *minimum* relevant question.  Did you really need to state all those constants to 10 significant figures?  Of course not.

Comment: Sorry, the basic problem was a physics case,not a math one, it was from a complicated dynamics of a fluid system. Posting the real problem is not suitable here.

Comment: But you would get essentially the same information from asking about plotting $1+2 cn^2(3x,4)$.  You could put in the actual values of the parameters yourself.

Comment: Yes, you're right and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Maple the function is JacobiCN, but the parameter is different: Maple uses the modulus $k$ where Mathematica uses the amplitude $k^2$.  So to get caverac's plot in Maple, you would use

```
plot(0.7951556995 + 0.0048443005*JacobiCN(0.4831042546*x, sqrt(0.1118800243))^2, x=0..5);
```

[image]